# Reading a JsonFile to an ArrayList

Tags: java

I have an assingment to create something on the lines of a quiz. The teacher gave us all the interfaces for the [Questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxku4.jpg) and the [Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4ebf.jpg) and even the "graphic layer" to [display the quiz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgCe2.jpg).

I created two classes for the Test and Question interfaces. The test class has a listArray of Questions objects along with other atributes. The Question class has the atributes you can see in the JSON File(title,score,mark,etc...).

To read the Json file i created the method "loadfromJsonFile", and it prints the file perfectly but i cant figure out how to associate each question object from the file to the arrayList.

Json File:

```
[
{
    "type": "MultipleChoice",
    "question": {
        "title": "Question 1",
        "score": 4,
        "mark":  5,
        "question_description": "The ability of an object to take on many forms is:",
        "options": [
            "Polymorphism",
            "Encapsulation",
            "Design Patter",
            "Does not Exist"
        ],
        "correct_answer": "Polymorphism"
    }
},

{
    "type": "MultipleChoice",
    "question": {
        "title": "Question 2",
        "score": 4,
        "mark":  5,
        "question_description": "The bundling of data with the methods that operate on that data is:",
        "options": [
            "Polymorphism",
            "Encapsulation",
            "Design Patter",
            "Does not Exist"
        ],
        "correct_answer": "Encapsulation"
    }
},
{
    "type": "YesNo",
    "question": {
        "title": "Question 3",
        "score": 4,
        "mark":  5,
        "question_description": "Object Oriented Programming is exclusive to the JAVA programming language",
        "correct_answer": "no"
    }
},
{
    "type": "Numeric",
    "question": {
        "title": "Question 4",
        "score": 4,
        "mark":  5,
        "question_description": "How many programming languages are taught in Paradigmas de Programação?",
        "correct_answer": "1"
    }
}]
```

Code for reading the Json File:

```
public boolean loadFromJSONFile(String s) throws TestException {
    String path = "teste_A.json";
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try{
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

        JsonStreamParser p = new JsonStreamParser(reader);
        JsonArray arr = (JsonArray) p.next();

        for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------Question"+i+"--------------------------------------------");
            JsonElement arrayElement = arr.get(i);
            JsonObject obj = arrayElement.getAsJsonObject();
            String type=obj.get("type").getAsString();
            System.out.println("Type: " + type);
            JsonObject list =obj.get("question").getAsJsonObject();
            String title=list.get("title").getAsString();
            System.out.println("Title: " + title);
            int score=list.get("score").getAsInt();
            System.out.println("Score: " + score);
            int mark=list.get("mark").getAsInt();
            System.out.println("Mark: " + mark);
            String Description=list.get("question_description").getAsString();
            System.out.println("Description: " + Description);
            JsonArray opt = list.getAsJsonArray("options");
            if(opt!=null){
                System.out.println("Options: \n");
                for (int j = 0; j < opt.size(); j++) {
                    JsonPrimitive value = opt.get(j).getAsJsonPrimitive();
                    System.out.print("      Option"+ (j+1) +": "+ value.getAsString()+ " \n");
                }
                System.out.println("\n");
            }

            String CorrectAnswer = list.get("correct_answer").getAsString();
            System.out.println("Correct: " + CorrectAnswer);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        }catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    return false;
}
```

Comment: You would like to read questions from the file, right? So the return type of your method shouldn't be `boolean`. It should be `List<Question>`: that's what you want your method to produce: a list of questions. Not a boolean. Given that the method will have to return a List of question, you'll have to create a list, create several Question objects, add each of them to the list, and finally return the list.

Comment: Unless you have specifically been required to parse the JSON from scratch, please don't. Use a serialisation/deserialization library instead, such as Jackson or Gson.

Comment: @JBNizet the problem is that the interface method returns a a boolean and it cant be changed. I asked the teacher if it was a typo but he said no

Comment: @John the teacher recommended us to use Gson but i found it easier to code like this.

Comment: Then its responsibility is probably to initilialize the object itself, i.e. initialize and populate `this.questions`. It doesn't make much difference to the above process. The only difference is that, at the end, instead of returning the list, it should initialize `this.questions with the created and populated list.

Comment: Your teacher is right! It doesn't have to be difficult, here is a good tutorial: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my understanding: you can read the json file and parse the contents just fine, but the issue is how to pass the results back to the caller without returning the parameter itself. From the code snippets, the line 
`this.current_question = this.test.getQuestion(this.question_number);`
seems like where this ArrayList will be queried in the program.

From this, I am imagining a couple of possibilites:

1) There is a `setQuestion(<params>)` method that you could call in the teacher's provided code.

2) There is a variable such as `this.test` or `this.questions` that you should be setting.

In either case, you would add each question inside your `for` loop. For example,

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------Question"+i+"--------------------------------------------");
            JsonElement arrayElement = arr.get(i);
            JsonObject obj = arrayElement.getAsJsonObject();
            //add obj via variable assignment
            this.test.Add(obj);
            //or, add obj via set method
            this.test.setQuestion(i, obj); //or whatever parameters are needed :)
```

EDIT:

Because your Question class extends IQuestion, you can cast an instance of the Question class to IQuestion. Plus, the Question class is using a Gson library to deserialize for you, which means you saved yourself some legwork. (yay!)

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){
            //get the whole json array element
            JsonElement arrayElement = arr.get(i);
            //...
            //get question object
            JsonObject list = obj.get("question").getAsJsonObject();
            //cast to IQuestion using the Question class Gson deserializer
            IQuestion q = new Gson().fromJson(list, Question.class);
            //And, add using built in method
            this.test.setQuestion(q);
```

[This website](https://www.baeldung.com/gson-deserialization-guide) has some examples of Gson deserialization, one of which I used up above.

EDIT:

After adding a constructor to the Question class, the code to add a question of specific types will need type casting.

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){
            //get the whole json array element
            JsonElement arrayElement = arr.get(i);
            //...
            //get question object
            JsonObject list = obj.get("question").getAsJsonObject();
            //cast question to correct interface based on question type
            if (type=="Multiple Choice") {
               IQuestionMultipleChoice questionMP = (IQuestionMultipleChoice) new Question(<params>);
               this.test.setQuestion(questionMP);
            } else if(type=="Yes/No") {
               //...
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195961/discussion-on-answer-by-nerdyginger-reading-a-jsonfile-to-an-arraylist).